# How can I change the visibility of the image in IE6 when it's in a td element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

What i want to do is to change visibility of the span element(which has a background image) when i hover it, which is stayed in a td element.

Everything works well in advanced browsers(including IE7,8), but it cant't work in IE6.

I can't figure it out. Have you guys encountered the same case as mine?

Code like the one below:

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <style>
     .btn{
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-position: 0 0;
        background-repeat: none;
        background-image: url('http://up.ekoooo.com/uploads2/allimg/091024/9_091024065737_1.jpg');
    }
    .default-hidden{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .hover .default-hidden{
        visibility: visible;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr onmouseover="this.className='hover';" onmouseout="this.className='';">
                <td>
                    2222222<span class="btn default-hidden">000000</span>33333
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

I registered inline mouseover and mouseout event on the tr element, when you mouseover it, and then the `hover` class was added to it; when you mouseout the tr and I just remove the `hover` class name.

thanks,
Khalil

Comment: People are still supporting IE6?

Comment: some statistics: major IE version in China is IE6, due to the use of pirated copy of Windows operating system (they cannot upgrade due to license check)

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right, Raptor. The share of IE6 is about 22%, you can check it in [browser share from baidu](http://tongji.baidu.com/data/browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event to `<td>` instead:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td onmouseover="this.className='hover';" onmouseout="this.className='';">2222222<span class="btn default-hidden">000000</span>33333</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez88a/)

**UPDATE**: To deal with IE6, you can change the table structure to DIV & CSS, which is supported by IE6. Since IE6 does not support `:hover` CSS selector, you can also use this fix to make use of `:hover` in IE6: http://blog.delivi.com/javascript/updated-hover-for-non-anchor-elements-in-ie6/

Comment: thanks for your quickly reply. I want to show the `td` when I hover the entire tr element, not just the td.

Comment: convert it to `<div>` instead. `<tr>` JS event is not well supported by IE6

Comment: yes, Raptor, you are right. The <div> works well. But in my case, it's a list, so I choose the table layout to get it. Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: No. you can't make IE6 to support its unsupported features.

Comment: Updated answer for alternate solution